# writing an equation with Matlab (Matrix size)

Tags: matlab, matrix, equation

Maybe my question is not relevant, but I really need a help ..

I have this equation on Matlab:

`returns(t,:)=IR(t-1+n,C)+rawreturns(t+n,:)*weights/(sum(abs(weights)))`;

`IR` is a vector and `rawreturns` is a matrix, is that  writing correct? Meaning, is it correct to sum a vector (r,1) with a matrix (r,c)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: could you add the variables' sizes?

Comment: How should we know if it is correct? We don't know what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: The code is in the following link (page 41, strategy 4): http://arno.uvt.nl/show.cgi?fid=127311

Answer (score 0):

As a simple example from what i understand I would say it should work

```
 A=[1;2;3;4;5];
 b=rand(5,3);
 b =[ 0.2322316   0.8267251   0.8388056
      0.0517476   0.6707926   0.2303345
      0.0081088   0.3644391   0.0703019
      0.6496504   0.6778138   0.3403278
      0.6505520   0.0227597   0.3787280]

 c=A+b
 c= [1.2322   1.8267   1.8388
     2.0517   2.6708   2.2303
     3.0081   3.3644   3.0703
     4.6497   4.6778   4.3403
     5.6506   5.0228   5.3787]
```

i hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I am sorry but it didn't work .. Matlab says "Matrix dimensions must agree"

Comment: aa what didnt work? is weights also a matrix? could you be a little specific as to what didnt work? as the example i gave above is working. atleast put your IR vector and rawreturns matrices as examples so they can be analysed.